# In a planar embedding of a graph, can vertices lie on each other?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

I am wondering if vertices of a planar graph can lie on top of each other in an embedding of the graph. Also, when drawing a picture/representation of the graph, is drawing vertices on top of vertices precluded?

thanks

Comment: I would distinguish between a *planar* graph and a *plane* graph. A plane graph is a graph that has been drawn in the plane without any edge-crossings. A planar graph is a graph that can be drawn in the plane without any edge-crossings, but with no assumption that anyone has drawn it that way, or even drawn it at all. You can draw a graph any way you want to, but it's not an embedding if two distinct vertices go to the same point.

Answer (score 2):

No. [The definition of a planar graph in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) does not make it clear, but I'm pretty sure they do not want to allow this. [The definition in Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlanarEmbedding.html) does say "no two vertices coincide". And [the Wikipedia definition of graph embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_embedding) says "no arcs include points associated with other vertices", which at least means that vertices which have any edges must be distinct in the embedding.

Drawing a graph with coinciding vertices is generally confusing, so I don't recommend it.